# Get <a href> contents based on text highlighted

Tags: javascript, html, selection, href, execcommand

I want to be able to identify if selected text contains a URL - the idea is that once a user selects text within a content editable div if it contains a URL - the URL is displayed in another content editable div to allow them to make corrections to the URL. Then if they make changes to the URL it then updates the `<a href>`.

I have currently created the code to allow the users to select any text and create a link its just the amendments thats causing the problem.

The code below is a section of my code where when the user selects an element of text it assigns # as the URL then they can write a http:// link into a content editable div called #link once the user has entered a http:// link it then updates # with the link.

```
document.getElementById("insertHTML").onclick = function(e) {
    var sText =document.getSelection();        
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<a href=# id ="data_link" target="_blank">' + sText + '</a>');
};

var contents = $('#link').html();
$('#link').blur(function() {
    if (contents!=$(this).html()){
        contents = $(this).html();
        document.getElementById('data_link').setAttribute('href', contents);
        document.getElementById('data_link').setAttribute('id', contents);
    }
    $('#link').empty();
});
```

any ideas would be great had no luck with anything online so far

Thanks Everyone  :)

Comment: many more people will be liekly to respond with a jsfiddle created ;)

Comment: It's confusing to mix jQuery with raw JS like that. Pick one and use it consistently.

Comment: The [HTML Editing APIs](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html) are not standardized and have [unclear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand#Browser_Compatibility) browser support. I would be very hesitant to use `document.execCommand` yet.

Answer (score 1):

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/w4p7a2kh/)

Select some text, you'll see it appears in the alert. You can uncomment the line with the url, make it your own url and place the text wherever you want it, I simply placed it where I did as an example of how you would implement this. When the text is selected, it will bring you to that url.

If you want to create an `input type="button" id="myInputButtonId"` etc to link to another page, then use

`$("#myInputButtonId").on('click', function(){`

instead of

`$("#writtenstuff").on('mouseup', function () {`

**HTML**

```
<div id="writtenstuff">
    <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#writtenstuff").on('mouseup', function () {

    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    if (text != "" && text != " ") {
        alert(text);
        //window.location.href = "http://www.someurl.com/"+text;
    }
});
```